# ElasticSearch get all fields even if their value is null

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to search ElasticSearch and retrieve specific fields from all records, no matter their value. But response contains for each record only the fields whose value is not **null**. Is there a way to force ElasticSearch to return the exact same number of fields for all records?

Example Request:

```
{
    "fields" : ["Field1","Field2","Field3"],
    "query" : {
        "match_all" : {}
    }
}
```

Example Response:

```
{
    "hits": [
        {
            "fields": {
                "Field1": [
                    "bla"
                ],
                "Field2": [
                    "test"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "fields": {
                "Field1": [
                    "bla"
                ],
                "Field2": [
                    "test"
                ],
                "Field3": [
                    "somevalue"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

My goal is to get something for `"Field3"` in the first hit.

Comment: Does the first document in your index have "Field3"?

Comment: No, it doesn't. The field exists in the index, but for the specific document there is no value.

Answer (score 1):

As per the guide given in the following link, It clearly says that any fields which has null,[] or "" are not stored or not indexed in the document. Its an inverted index concept and has to be handled in the program explicitly.

link - http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_dealing_with_null_values.html